# How to create a pygame window on the framebuffer without covering the entire screen?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, notifications, framebuffer

I'm not sure if what I'd like to do is possible using pygame. I have a raspberry pi hooked up to a projector, and for the sake of performance I've been using it strictly without an X server. I use it for movies, coding, email, chatting, music, and playing games.

What I'm trying to create is a way to popup notification bubbles on the framebuffer. At present I'm using a library called [fbpy](https://github.com/noisegate/fbpy), but it's fairly lacking, especially when it comes to drawing text.

The result looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

The font is static; it converts all text to uppercase; and it only supports A-Z. I would love to dig in and update the library to support a wider range of fonts and characters, but I just don't have the time. I'm hoping that I can replicate this setup using pygame, but I can't figure out how to (if it's even possible) write to only a portion of the framebuffer instead of covering the entire screen.

Comment: What have you tried yourself to achieve what you want? You write you don't have the time to work on what you want to have, so why should someone else have the time to help you with pygame?

Comment: If you take the time to look at the [pygame documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/), you'll discover that it's very easy to set the size of the pygame window with `pygame.display.set_mode(size)` where `size` is a `tuple` containing the width and height desired: `(800, 600)` for example.

Comment: @Claudio: That's fair. So far I've had to go in and help finish or roughly patch some of the code in fbpy since it's still very much in a development state. Once finals are out of the way, I'd love to actually get the library to a rather functional state and submit some pull requests to the repo or fork it. I found that library uses svg files to write characters, so I tried (and successfully) exported the characters in __import__("string").printable to individual files, but the svg parser used by fbpy is minimal at best and couldn't successfully translate the svg files to polylines.

Comment: @Claudio: As far as pygame is concerned, I've tried all sorts of different display modes, but each one seems to create a black border or stretch the window to fill the entire screen when you're writing directly to the framebuffer as opposed to running pygame within an X server. I've also tried setting the main window background to transparent then creating a subsurface, but that, too, doesn't seem to work when writing to the framebuffer

Comment: @martineau: I have actually played with pygame fairly extensively :/ I've tried setting the mode to a smaller size, and that either stretches the window to fill the entire screen or creates a black border that covers the visible screen (when writing directly to the frame buffer). Attempting to make the background transparent doesn't seem to work, either.

Comment: You can get the address of the raw pixel bytes of a [`pygame.Surface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html), so you might be able to copy its contents to a portion of the framebuffer.

Comment: @martineau: That's awesome! So I'm using [this code](https://pastebin.com/WufWv6R7) to attempt to write to the framebuffer. It looks like this might be the right track to doing what I want? The expected result with this code is that I would have a red rectangle displayed in the upper right portion of the screen. But instead I get [this](http://i.imgur.com/zkBfs02.png) if I write "surf.get_buffer().raw" and [this](http://i.imgur.com/OmaNizL.png) if I write "screen.get_buffer().raw"

Comment: I don't know what the `.raw` does, but the results look promising. The most likely reason the red rectangle is being sheared is because the pitch (or pixels-per-row) of it an the framebuffer aren't the same. This can be fixed by processing the buffer a row-at-a-time with a differing memory-offset for the destination for each line in the framebuffer. The memory offset each iteration will be the number of pixels in each row of the framebuffer.